# Подключить образ жёсткого диска

Tags: windows, ntfs, диск, образ, поиск-программ

В линуксе при помощи команды `cp /dev/sda1 c.img` создан файл c образом раздела жёсткого диска с файловой системой NTFS (размер 80ГБ).

Как его подключить в Windows 7 (желательно в readonly режиме)?
Устраивают встроенные средства или бесплатные (для коммерческого использования) программы.

Программы для iso-образов предлагайте только если уверены, что они способны работать с этим образом. Например, при монтировании при помощи Virtual CloneDrive смонтированный диск использовать невозможно:

> [Window Title]
>   Microsoft Windows
>   
>   [Main Instruction]
>   Windows can't access this disc
>   
>   [Content]
>   The disc might be corrupt. Make sure that the disc uses a format that Windows recognizes. If the disc is unformatted, you need to format it before using it.
>   
>   [Close]

Comment: http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html ?

Comment: или http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_converting.html

Comment: смотри что нагуглил http://wincmd.ru/plugring/virtdisk.html

Comment: @VladD, http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html - то что нужно! Как-то нашёл или уже пользовался? А то у меня всё про vhd гуглилось. PS: Напиши как ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy: сделано!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows на текущий момент не умеет монтировать raw image (но начиная с какой-то версии научилась монтировать .vhd-образ).

Можно использовать внешнюю программу, которая представит raw image как диск. Например: http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

Comment: Программу нашёл по какому-то запросу, или уже пользовался ей? А то, у меня только уйма информации по vhd нагуглилась.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не пользовался. (Поэтому начал с комментария.)

Answer (score 1):

Я использую программу [Freeware Linux Reader for Windows](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/). Она позволяет работать с сырыми образами, так и с дисковыми контейнерами от виртуальных машин: vmdk к примеру. Далее она пользователю пользователю в проводник-подобном окружении ходить по файловой системе "примонтированного" образа и в случае чего может сохранить(извлечь) файл. По факту программа парсит ФС. Но пользователю отображается, как будто образ примонтирован.

Минусы "OSFmount": в примонированном диске\разделе\образе могут иметься ссылки(Junktion), которые могут вести на какую-либо из папок реальной ФС.

Comment: Да, символьные ссылки имеются, но, в данном случае, это не проблема.